# How to make listview work correctly in my app

Tags: android, listview

[image: Food Diary]
                                                     I have this Food Diary layout. Under the Add Food Button for each of the Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner Headings. A listview should appear with a list of food items added in it. Initially it will be empty so it should appear with the food items when something gets added in it.

I've written the xml for the layout but I haven't been able to successfully set the listview in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="20"
tools:context="hamza.example.fitkitapp.Food_Diary">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
        android:text="@string/FoodDiary"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
        android:textSize="@dimen/topBarText" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="Today"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:background="@color/colorgray"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="2,230"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView101"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="8"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView100"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="="
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView102"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="1,230"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView105"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
  </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="Goal"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView106"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="Food"
    android:textSize="15sp
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView107"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:text="Remaining"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView108"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorDarkBlue"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:text="Calories"/>
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:text="Carbs"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:text="Fat"/>
 <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="15sp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="255dp"
   android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
   android:text="Protein"/>

 <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="15sp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
   android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
   android:text="Sugars"/>
    </FrameLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkBlue"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
            android:text="kcal"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
            android:text="g"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="232dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
            android:text="g"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="275dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
            android:text="g"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="325dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
            android:text="g"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="Breakfast"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:gravity="start|center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:background="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
    android:layout_weight="0.05" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/addFood1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-250dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="  Add Food"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
        android:textSize="19dp" />

  </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewBreakfast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
    </ListView>


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="Lunch"
    android:id="@+id/lunch"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:gravity="start|center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:background="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
    android:layout_weight="0.05" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add"
        android:id="@+id/addFood2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-250dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="  Add Food"
        android:id="@+id/add_lunch"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
        android:textSize="19dp" />

  </LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="Dinner"
    android:gravity="start|center"
    android:id="@+id/dinner"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:background="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
    android:layout_weight="0.05" />


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/addFood3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-250dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="  Add Food"
        android:id="@+id/add_dinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
        android:textSize="19dp" />

 </LinearLayout>


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="Totals"
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:gravity="start|center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:background="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
    android:layout_weight="0.05" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="35dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Goals"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2,230"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1011"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="278"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1012"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="74"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1013"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="111"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1014"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2,300"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1015"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/divider"
    />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="35dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Remaining"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_weight="0.19" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2,230"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGreenCalories"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1041"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="278"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGreenCalories"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1042"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="74"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGreenCalories"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView101443"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="111"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGreenCalories"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView10444"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2,300"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGreenCalories"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView10435"
    android:layout_weight="0.24" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Make Entry"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorgray"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/Btn_MakeEntry"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.10" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/Home"
        android:id="@+id/Btn_Home1"
        android:background="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="@string/FoodDiary"
        android:id="@+id/Btn_FD1"
        android:background="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="@string/Progress"
        android:id="@+id/Btn_Progress1"
        android:background="@color/colorBlueTopBar"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteTopBarText"
        />

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it somehow possible to let it grow and not affect the Lunch textview below it?

[Update 1]
I tried with the expandable listview. Made three of them under the Breakfast,Lunch and Dinner Headings. I haven't been successful with them also.

Answer (score 0):

You can't not affect all the stuff below. I suggest placing it in a listview though, so that the user can scroll through.

Comment: Please bear with me as I'm new to Android, you mean placing all the stuff from Breakfast till Dinner inside a ListView?

Comment: @HamzaBinAmin Yes, because a listview is scrollable. So, just put everything in a listview, and you won't have problems when adding items. Please press the check mark to accept my answer if it works. If you have more questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: I tried putting listview with wrap content parameters like you said and it gives out an exception "Exception raised during rendering: addView(View, Layoutparms) is not supported in AdapterView"

Answer (score 0):

Use expandable listview where addfood will be parent and add fooditems as its child view. You will have to use three different listviews for three categories.

Comment: can I reference the textview of addFood from the existing xml file that I have or will I have to make separate child and parent xml files for referencing?

Comment: Use separate xml file for both parent and child otherwise things will become complex to handle

Comment: Tried with separate parent and child xml files. still doesn't work. I can post the entire code here if you want, but it exceeds the word limit